# Visual Basic - Simple Bank Transaction

Tags: vb.net

I believe everything is working correctly but I cannot get the labels to display the calculated data, don't know where I messed up here. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Dim decMakeWithdrawal As Decimal
    Dim decBalace As Decimal

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        'Close the form
        Me.Close()
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnDeposit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeposit.Click
        Dim decMakeDeposit As Decimal

        'Add Deposit
        decMakeDeposit = CDec(InputBox("Please enter deposit if you have any"))
    End Sub

    Public Sub btnWithdraw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWithdraw.Click
        Dim decBalance As Decimal

        decMakeWithdrawal = CDec(InputBox("Please enter an amount to withdraw"))
        If decBalance <= 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Insufficient funds")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim decIntRate As Decimal

        decIntRate = CDec(InputBox("Please enter the interest rate:"))

    End Sub

    Private Function decintTrans() As Object
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim decInterTrans As Decimal
        Dim decInterest As Decimal

        decInterest = CDec(decintTrans())
        decInterTrans += 1D
    End Sub
End Class

    Public Class Transaction
    'Create member variables for properties

    Public decBalance As Decimal
    Private decIntRate As Decimal
    Private decInterest As Decimal
    Private intTrans As Integer
    Private decMakeWithdrawal As Decimal
    Private decMakeDeposit As Decimal
    Private decInterestEarned As Decimal


    'Create property procedures
    Public Property Balance As Decimal
        Get
            Return decBalance
        End Get

        Set(value As Decimal)
            decBalance = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property IntRate As Double
        Get
            Return decIntRate
        End Get

        Set(value As Double)
            decIntRate = CDec(value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property InterestTotal As Double
        Get
            Return decInterest
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            decInterest = CDec(value)
        End Set
    End Property



    'calculate the amount of interest for the current period 
    'stores this value in the Interest property, and adds it to the Balance property
    Public Sub addInterest(ByVal addInterest As Integer)
        decInterestEarned = decBalance * (decIntRate / 12)
    End Sub


    'add deposit
    Public Sub addDeposit(ByVal addDeposit As Decimal)
        decMakeDeposit += addDeposit

    End Sub

    'withdraw
    Public Sub subtractWithdrawl(ByVal subtractWithdrawal As Double)
        If decMakeWithdrawal >= subtractWith() Then
            decMakeWithdrawal = CDec(decMakeWithdrawal - subtractWith())
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No sufficient balance")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function subtractWith() As Double
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: I don't see any labels referenced anywhere in the code you posted. can you indicate which statement(s) tries to update a label but fails? Also, you should use [Decimal.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to validate the input strings before converting them to `Decimal` variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel your code is being complicated by stuff you have added that you are not using at present.

So to simply things, I've cut the extra stuff out and corrected any errors I could see. A lot of tweaking is still needed and like member blackwood states you should validate the values input by the user before processing the data.

Yet still, simply to start you off and set you on the right path, try the code below and don't forget to compare it to your original so you can see where you were going wrong.

Good luck

```
Option Explicit
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Dim MyTransactor as Transaction

Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Dim decIntRate As Decimal
  MyTransactor = New Transaction()
  decIntRate = CDec(InputBox("Please enter the interest rate:"))
  MyTransactor.IntRate = decintRate
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
  'Close the form
  Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnDeposit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeposit.Click
  Dim decMakeDeposit As Decimal
  decMakeDeposit = CDec(InputBox("Please enter deposit if you have any"))
  MyTransactor.addDeposit = decMakeDeposit 
End Sub

Public Sub btnWithdraw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWithdraw.Click
  decMakeWithdrawal = CDec(InputBox("Please enter an amount to withdraw"))
  MyTransactor.subtractWithdrawl = decMakeWithdrawal 
End Sub

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
  MyTransactorAddInterest
  MessageBox.Show(MyTransactor.InterestEarned &  "Interest add to balance. Total balance now is " & MyTranasactor.Balance)
End Sub

End Class






Public Class Transaction

'Create member variables for properties
Public decBalance As Decimal
Private decIntRate As Decimal
Private decInterestEarned As Decimal

'Create property procedures
Public Property Balance As Decimal
  Get
    Return decBalance
  End Get
  Set(value As Decimal)
    decBalance = value
  End Set
End Property

Public Property IntRate As Double
  Get
    Return decIntRate
  End Get
  Set(value As Double)
    decIntRate = CDec(value)
  End Set
End Property

Public Property InterestEarned As Double
  Get
    Return decInterestEarned 
  End Get
  Set(value As Double)
    decInterestEarned = CDec(value)
  End Set
End Property

'calculate the amount of interest for the current period 
'stores this value in the Interest property, and adds it to the Balance property
Public Sub AddInterest()
  decInterestEarned = decBalance * (decIntRate / 12)
  decBalance =+ decInterestEarned 
End Sub

'add deposit
Public Sub addDeposit(ByVal DepositValue As Decimal)
  decBalance=+ DepositValue
End Sub

'withdraw
Public Sub subtractWithdrawl(ByVal WithdrawalValue As Double)
  If decBalance >= WithdrawalValue Then
    decBalance =-  WithdrawalValue 
  Else
    MessageBox.Show("No sufficient balance")
  End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you! I will keep working on this and hopefully get to where I need to be.